Spring Boot NamedParameterJdbcTemplate execute complex Insert Query
I want run a multi insert query but getting this error
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
Table Schema
create table if not exists student
(
student_id bigserial primary key,
student_name text
);

create table if not exists favourite_color
(
student_id bigint,
color text,
foreign key (student_id) references student (student_id)
);

create table if not exists favourite_animal
(
student_id bigint,
animal text,
foreign key (student_id) references student (student_id)
);

Working SQL Query
do $$
declare s_id bigint;
declare fav_color text;
declare s_name text;
declare fav_animal text;
begin
fav_color := 'Red';
fav_animal := 'Horse';
s_name := 'jhon';
insert into student (student_name)
values(s_name)
returning student_id into s_id;

insert into favourite_color(student_id,color)
values (s_id, fav_color);

insert into favourite_animal (student_id,animal)
values (s_id, fav_animal);
end
$$;

Spring Boot Code [Not Working]
public  void addStudent() {
        String sql = """
                do $$
                declare s_id bigint; declare fav_color text;
                declare s_name text; declare fav_animal text;
                begin
                fav_color := :color;
                fav_animal := :animal;
                s_name := :name;
                insert into student (student_name)
                values(s_name)
                returning student_id into s_id;
                
                insert into favourite_color(student_id,color)
                values (s_id, fav_color);
                
                insert into favourite_animal (student_id,animal)
                values (s_id, fav_animal);
                end
                $$;
                """;
        MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        parameters.addValue("name", "Jhon");
        parameters.addValue("animal", "Horse");
        parameters.addValue("color", "Blue");
        template.update(sql, parameters);

    }

When I run the code, it should insert the values in designated tables.
Error
 2024-06-05T17:05:50.816Z DEBUG 260 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
 2024-06-05T17:05:50.816Z DEBUG 260 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [do $$
 declare s_id bigint; declare fav_color text;
 declare s_name text; declare fav_animal text;
 begin
 fav_color := ?;
 fav_animal := ?;
 s_name := ?;
 insert into student (student_name)
 values(s_name)
 returning student_id into s_id;
 
 insert into favourite_color(student_id,color)
 values (s_id, fav_color);
 
 insert into favourite_animal (student_id,animal)
 values (s_id, fav_animal);
 end
 $$;
 ]
 2024-06-05T17:05:50.836Z DEBUG 260 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [do $$
 declare s_id bigint; declare fav_color text;
 declare s_name text; declare fav_animal text;
 begin
 fav_color := ?;
 fav_animal := ?;
 s_name := ?;
 insert into student (student_name)
 values(s_name)
 returning student_id into s_id;
 
 insert into favourite_color(student_id,color)
 values (s_id, fav_color);
 
 insert into favourite_animal (student_id,animal)
 values (s_id, fav_animal);
 end
 $$;
 ]; The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
 2024-06-05T17:05:50.837Z ERROR 260 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [do $$
 declare s_id bigint; declare fav_color text;
 declare s_name text; declare fav_animal text;
 begin
 fav_color := ?;
 fav_animal := ?;
 s_name := ?;
 insert into student (student_name)
 values(s_name)
 returning student_id into s_id;
 
 insert into favourite_color(student_id,color)
 values (s_id, fav_color);
 
 insert into favourite_animal (student_id,animal)
 values (s_id, fav_animal);
 end
 $$;
 ]; The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.] with root cause
 
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
         at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:70) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]
         at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setStringParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:133) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]
         at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.bindString(PgPreparedStatement.java:1064) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]
         at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setString(PgPreparedStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]
         at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setString(PgPreparedStatement.java:351) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]
         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setString(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:440) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:247) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:163) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.setValues(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:287) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.createPreparedStatement(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:245) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:656) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:970) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:991) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:337) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at ncr.opencheck.checkcalculator.checkcalculatorservice.repository.impl.OrderRepositoryImpl.addStudent(OrderRepositoryImpl.java:61) ~[main/:na]
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
         at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:717) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at ncr.opencheck.checkcalculator.checkcalculatorservice.repository.impl.OrderRepositoryImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.addStudent(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
         at ncr.opencheck.checkcalculator.checkcalculatorservice.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl.validateAndCalculateOrder(OrderServiceImpl.java:20) ~[main/:na]
         at ncr.opencheck.checkcalculator.checkcalculatorservice.controller.OrderController.validateAndCalculateOrder(OrderController.java:22) ~[main/:na]
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:261) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:6.0]
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:6.0]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]


Observation
When I am running the query without template placeholders, putting the values directly its working as expected, and no errors are thrown.
Postgres Driver 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.8'

As far as I know, JDBC prepared statements and named parameter JDBC don't work with SQL DO, because of it's dynamic nature. To solve multiple queries at once there is batchUpdate, however the only solution that comes to my mind for your case is to save the student first, get it's id using getGeneratedKeys() and then perform the insert on the favourite_color and favourite_animal (batchUpdate can be used for adding to favourite tables).
